# How to display a scrolling banner with alert on a Salesforce record page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have several questions.

1. How do I post below VisualForce message to be displayed to the Quote record page so when user clicks on the page, they will view this. 
   Your help is greatly appreciated.
2. How do I only show this message when **Status is DRAFT?**

Markup:

```
<apex:page >
    showheader="false" sidebar="false">
    <style>
    h1
    {
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size: 40px;
       }
    </style>
    <apex:form >
    <div style="background-color: red;width: 100%">
    <marquee scrollamount="15"> <h1>
    Please save the "PDF Quote" document prior to clicking on the "Submit for Approval." </h1>
    </marquee>
    </div>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`marquee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) is deprecated, and you should not use it. It may not work in future browsers. As far as showing/hiding the message, you can use [`apex:outputText`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm):

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!Quote.Status='draft'}">
  You cannot do this, blah blah blah...
</apex:outputText>
```

You can use other styles, of course, like [slds](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/); the warning above is specifically about the use of `marquee`.

Comment: Thank you SFDCFOX!  Now my next questions is how do I display this code to show in the page layout?  I'm new to the development world so your help is very much needed.

Comment: @LN Just set the standard controller: `<apex:page standardController="Quote">`, then you can drag the page in to the page layout.

Comment: sfdcfox, it worked!

Comment: Another thing I noticed it doesn't show on top of the page but rather in a field.  Is there a way to show the banner on top of the page?

Comment: @LN no, you can only put visualforce in certain places.